# Create And Execute Tasks in A Row

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application in which i want to execute the tasks from only 1 place so that every time i add new Task it is added to that row to be executed, Also i want a priority for each task so if i set the task priority to HIGH it is added to the top of the row so it is executed immediately, On the other hand if i set the priority to Low it is added to the end of the row and so on...

I thought about using Tasks and ContinueWith but i don't have any clue from where should i start to have a class that totally handles my needs.

I am sorry for not providing a code or something bug i hope someone can get the point that i am pointing to and help me. And thank you in advance .

Comment: you should at least show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you *didn't* need to make room for high-priority tasks, you could make a simple helper class using `Task` and `ContinueWith`:

```
public class SimpleWorkQueue
{
    private Task _main = null;

    public void AddTask(Action task)
    {
        if (_main == null)
        {
            _main = new Task(task);
            _main.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            Action<Task> next = (t) => task();
            _main = _main.ContinueWith(next);
        }
    }
}
```

If you *do* need high-priority tasks, you probably need to handle more stuff yourself. Here is a producer/consumer example where all incoming tasks are inserted into a list in `AddTask()`, and a single worker thread consumes tasks from that list:

```
public class PrioritizedWorkQueue
{
    List<Action> _queuedWork;
    object _queueLocker;
    Thread _workerThread;

    public PrioritizedWorkQueue()
    {
        _queueLocker = new object();
        _queuedWork = new List<Action>();

        _workerThread = new Thread(LookForWork);
        _workerThread.IsBackground = true;
        _workerThread.Start();
    }
    private void LookForWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Action work;
            lock (_queueLocker)
            {
                while (!_queuedWork.Any()) { Monitor.Wait(_queueLocker); }

                work = _queuedWork.First();
                _queuedWork.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            work();
        }
    }

    public void AddTask(Action task, bool highPriority)
    {
        lock (_queueLocker)
        {
            if (highPriority)
            {
                _queuedWork.Insert(0, task);
            }
            else
            {
                _queuedWork.Add(task);
            }
            Monitor.Pulse(_queueLocker);
        }
    }

}
```